# Why does border-image-width occur twice in border-image formal syntax?

Tags: css

[Here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-border-image) is how W3C spec defines border-image property.
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) is how MDN explains border-image property.

In both of them, the formal syntax is:

> <'border-image-source'> || <'border-image-slice'> [ /
>   <'border-image-width'> | / <'border-image-width'>? /
>   <'border-image-outset'> ]? || <'border-image-repeat'>

I understand what [||](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax#Double_bar) , [|](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax#Single_bar) , [?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax#Question_mark_()) means.

Why does `border-image-width` occur twice in formal syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break that section down:

```
[ / <‘border-image-width’> | / <‘border-image-width’>? / <‘border-image-outset’> ]?
```

The properties are within brackets (`[ ]`). This means they are one group.

The single bar (`|`) divides the group into two sections:

1. `<‘border-image-width’>`
2. `<‘border-image-width’>? / <‘border-image-outset’>`

*The single bar is the key factor to answering your question.*

It defines `border-image-width` as part of two different use cases. It can appear by itself or with `border-image-outset`. Per the single bar definition, only one of these cases can occur.

The question mark (`?`) after `border-image-width` and after the brackets means it can appear zero or one time.

So these are the valid options for this group:

- `border-image-width`
- `border-image-outset`
- `border-image-width` & `border-image-outset`
- nothing

To really understand why `border-image-width` is needed twice, try to replicate those four options with only one `border-image-width`.